# Fetching data through html from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ectmE.png)

I am trying to make a database of passport applicants who will be able to know the status of their passports through the html form that's shown in the image attached above. But, what's the best way to do this and by using which form of database? Thank you.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. SO questions should be about a specific coding issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

With just HTML you cannot do it.

Either go with server side apps like PHP and use jQuery so user wont see the page getting refreshed.

Or go with Node JS framework.

Comment: How do I extract an individual's information from a database that's going to be connected to my html or php file, an example source code for that connection would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the simple CRUD operation.

Its too much to type in this comment box.. so sharing the link.

https://www.taniarascia.com/create-a-simple-database-app-connecting-to-mysql-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a REST Api to fulfill your requirement.There are lots of tutorials on various websites that you can learn those things.Simply CRUD operation means Create,Read,Update,Delete.

First of all study about databases and their usages.If you are going to use nodejs solution i'm recommending you for go to mongoDb.Or else if you are using PHP based solution, Mysql will be ideal.Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my cases I use ASP.NET Model View Controller Framework with the Entity Framework, with MSSQL Databases. It does use C# for the server side, but I find it pretty easy to use since it generates the basic CRUD operations for you when you connect the database.

Here is a great tutorial on doing this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/how-to-connect-ado-net-entity-framework-with-mvc-in-simple-s/

Good luck!